# Способы обновления Android приложения с сервера

Tags: android, update, flutter, version

Я разрабатываю приложение внутри компании, которое будет работать на устройствах под управлением Android. У меня появился вопрос, как лучше всего сделать обновление приложения с сервера?

Пока что я вижу такой вариант:

1. Файл будет храниться на сервере и будет доступен для скачивания по ссылке. Рядом с файлом будет находиться файл, к примеру "version.json", в котором будет храниться версия текущей программы.
2. При открытии приложения будет скачан файл "version.json" и будет проверена какая версия программы на данный момент актуальная. Если версия текущего приложения будет меньше чем версия из файла, будет выполнена закачка нового файла apk, для дальнейшей ее установки.

На сколько хорош данный способ? Есть ли какие то другие способы обновления корпоративного приложения с корпоративного сервера? Каким способом лучше всего делать обновление приложения? Возможно ли сделать автоматическую закачку и установку приложения с сервера на подобии как в PlayMarket? Просветите пожалуйста в данном вопросе.

P.S. Приложение реализовано на Flutter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы расписали только способ получения информации о новой версии (т.е. есть новая версия или нет).

В принципе ничего страшного в том, что вы скачивание json и смотрите там информацию нет(там же всегда будет информация только о новой версии).

А вот метод установки обновления тут может быть разный:

1. Если нет ROOT прав и ваше приложение не является системным:

Скачиваете новую версию и предлагаете пользователю при запуске приложения(или в любое удобное время) выполнить обновление. Запускаете intent на открытие apk, пользователь вручную устанавливает обновление.

2. Если есть root или ваше приложение системное:

Скачиваете новую версию и предлагаете пользователю при запуске приложения(или в любое удобное время) выполнить обновление. Запускаете intent на открытие apk, пользователь вручную устанавливает обновление или скачиваете apk и выполняете shell команду на установку/обновление .

Команда типа этого `pm install -r test.apk`

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое)